# Change style of button when trigger enter key

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner at HTML/CSS and JavaScript.

I wanna make a `button` with being triggered by **ENTER** keypress. The problem is that when i hover the button or click at it, it changes the background color while entering "ENTER" key doesn't.
I want to change the background color of the button when I press the ENTER key.

```js
document.getElementById("password").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("buttonpw").click();
  }
});

function mypassword() {
  var x = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (x === "SolitaryRJin") {
    alert("It's not for You. Bye bye!!");
  } else {
    alert("It's not for You. Bye bye!!");
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 149px;
  height: 43px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #000;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

button:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

button:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id='password' class='pass' onfocus="" class='inc1' type="password" name="Password" placeholder='Password' value="">
<button id='buttonpw' onclick="mypassword()">Sign In</button>
```

Comment: enter  on button or textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class on click enter and use class name in css..

**EDIT!**

to your comment to change style then show alert use `setTimeout`:https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```js
document.getElementById("password")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        var element =document.getElementById("buttonpw");
        element.click();
    }
});
function mypassword(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    alert('you did it!');
 },500);
     var element =document.getElementById("buttonpw");
  element.classList.add("clicked");   
}
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 149px;
  height: 43px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #000;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
button:hover, .clicked{
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}
button:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<input id='password' class='pass' onfocus="handle1()" class='inc1' type="password" name="Password" placeholder='Password' value="">
<button id='buttonpw' onclick="mypassword()">Sign In</button>
</html>
```

Comment: tell for more help

Comment: thank you, but it just changes after finishing to alert, not at pressing enter key.

Comment: so put those line in click function

Comment: can you tell me more details :( ? i'm just a beginner.

Comment: do you create onclick button function?

Comment: it's still the same as the previous one...it just changes after finishing to alert, not at pressing enter key

Comment: so put it before alert

Comment: tell me if it helps you

Comment: it works!! many thanks :(((. but i still wonder how it becomes normal when i typed the wrong password, because it still keep that .clicked style . how to recover it back to original style when being typed wrong password?

Comment: use removeclass:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside `if` - `document.getElementById("buttonpw").setAttribute("style", "color: #000;background: #fff;");`
Like this:

```
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
document.getElementById("buttonpw").setAttribute("style", "color: #000; 
background: #fff;");
document.getElementById("buttonpw").click();
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it just changes after finishing to alert, not at pressing enter key.

Comment: Add `.button:active {color: #000;  background: #fff;}` in css