# Why does pressing Enter on a button not cause :active state in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

Check the following snippet in current Chrome (80):

```js
foo.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('button activated');
})
```

```css
button:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="foo">Activate me using Click, Enter, Space</button>
```

Chrome applies the `button:active` styles when the button is **clicked** (right or left) or activated using <kbd>Space</kbd>, **but not when activated using** <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Firefox only applies the `button:active` styles when **clicking** (left mouse button only) the button.

Does anyone know

1. how this is *supposed to work*, and
2. how do I get the button to show `button:active` no matter which of
   the activation methods are used?

**I'd highly prefer a solution based on CSS.** Adding/removing a class using key listeners would be a very ugly solution and is not in the scope of this question.

### Edit

There has to be, or at least there should be, a standard way to give the user activating a button using <kbd>Enter</kbd> visual feedback on their action. **Is this behaviour not specified somewhere?** If it were, I could raise it as an issue on Mozilla bug tracker and also on Chromium issue tracker.

Comment: I think you're looking for `:focus` not active?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger the :active pseudoclass on keyboard 'enter' press? (using only CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467397/how-to-trigger-the-active-pseudoclass-on-keyboard-enter-press-using-only-cs) OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189109/change-the-style-the-button-when-trigger-enter-key

Comment: @Awais Unfortunately not really. There has got to be a standard way to give a user visual feedback when he activates a button using Enter, no?

Comment: @connexo but in the second link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189109/change-style-of-button-when-trigger-enter-key you will see when i put password and press enter the UI of button changes Isn't that what you mean to say

Comment: I'm - as stated in the question - not looking for Javascript based solution. There should be a solution that even works if for whatever reason Javascript is not available.

Comment: @TylerH Neither of the linked questions answer the "missing spec?!?" question.

Comment: Based on the spec, it's up to vendors to decide what to implement beyond the example given (pressing a mouse button), specifically it's up to them how to implement what constitutes "activating". If you think Chrome should do this, you should file a bug. The first duplicate target directly answers your first question (and the question you ask in the title), and the second duplicate target answers both your first and your second question, at least as I read them.

Comment: @TylerH If an interaction has the same consequences as a mouse click has, it is clearly an **activating action**. As such, the spec isn't even unclear about this, it just could - and probably should! - be more explicit.

Comment: how you can activate the button using space? I am not able to do this. I am able only to do it on click

Comment: [How to trigger the :active pseudoclass on keyboard 'enter' press? (using only CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467397/how-to-trigger-the-active-pseudoclass-on-keyboard-enter-press-using-only-cs)

Answer (score 6):

The specification seems quite clear about this:

> The `:active` pseudo-class applies **while an element is being activated by the user**. *For example*, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it. On systems with more than one mouse button, `:active` applies only to the primary or primary activation button (typically the "left" mouse button), and any aliases thereof.
>
> https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#sel-active

So it does *not explicitly* mention activating an element using the keyboard, but it does state

> [...] **while an element is being activated by the user** [...]

Since a button is clearly being **activated by the user** when he issues <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>, both Firefox and Chrome seem in clear violation of the spec here.

On top of that, Chrome also applies `:active` when **rightclicking** the button (which is explicitly stated in the spec should **not** be the case).

Will file an issue in the CSSWG tracker for making this part of the spec more explicit. Here it is: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4787

Comment: *Since a button is clearly being activated by the user when he issues Enter or Space,* --> how? I am not finding a trivial way to activate a button using enter or space.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Of course it needs to have focus, so you have navigated to it using the Tab key probably.

Comment: `:active` state is generally overlooked like it was nothing. Thanks for filing the issue, btw!